# Basic question about polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

A polynomial can be represented as

$a_{0} + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2} + ... +  a_{n}x^{n}$

where $a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$ the set of real numbers.

Why it is true that $a_{j}x^{j} \neq a_{k}x^{k} $ for $j \neq k$.

I have this question in the context of proving that the set $\{1,x,x^{2},...,x^{n}\}$ form a linearly independent set.

Comment: So let's say $j =2 $and $k =3$, you  are asking why $a_2 x^2 \neq a_3x^3$?These are different curves.

Comment: I mean the only way for the sum of your set to be $0$ is if all the weights on it are $0$.

Comment: This depends on your definition of polynomials.  Are you talking about polynomials as functions, or as formal expressions?

Comment: It seems apparent. Why does this become a question?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Eric's comment - the only sense in which your statement is true is if you think of polynomials as formal expressions; for clarity, the functions are called "polynomial functions" as opposed to "polynomials." And in that sense (of formal polynomials, an algebraic construction), the statement is true by definition. A polynomial is a finite sequence $(a_0, \dots, a_n, 0, 0, \dots)$, and operations on polynomials are defined as operations on such sequences.

Then if you introduce the notation $x$ for $(0, 1, 0, \dots)$ you find that $a_0 + a_1x + \cdots = (a_0, a_1, \dots);$ $a_jx^j = a_kx^k$ still means that the sequence with $a_j$ in the $j^{\text{th}}$ position and $0$ everywhere else equals the sequence with $a_k$ in the $k^{\text{th}}$ position and $0$ everywhere else - which forces $j=k$ and $a_j = a_k$ (or else $j \ne k$ and $a_j = a_k = 0$).